# How to verify user has authenticated via secure lock screen credentials

Tags: android, android-keystore

`KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` signifies that a Key in the Android Key Store is only authorized when:

> The user is authenticated using a subset of their secure lock screen
>   credentials (pattern/PIN/password, fingerprint).

If enabled, `UserNotAuthenticatedException` will be thrown any time a Key is generated or the KeyStore is accessed when the user is not authenticated.

Is there an API call to reliably check that the user is indeed authenticated prior to interacting with the KeyStore?...rather than relying solely on catching the exception after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Android provides the ability to check this through `KeyguardManager`

Here is some Kotlin code to help you out:

```
val kgManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
kgManager.isKeyguardSecure //true if the user set up their Lock Screen securely.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @HoppyKlaus.  Unfortunately, your solution does not answer my question.  It determines if the user has secured their mobile device -- i.e., set a pattern / PIN / password.  However, it does not tell me if the user will be required to to enter their secure lock credentials prior to me accessing the KeyStore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API, you have to catch the exception and handle it to ask user authentication when using pattern/PIN/password.

One solution if targeting API 23+ and only using Fingerprint is to use the `FingerprintManager` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html

You have an example on how to use it there:

- https://github.com/deivitaka/AndroidFingerprintAPI
- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog